# How to get the values from json object in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am not able to get the values from json object in nodejs.I am getting always undefined message for json object key.May be this response sync or asyn in nodejs.I do not know how to resolve this issue.Anyone can resolve this issue?

data.controller.js

```
module.exports.insertData = (req, res, next) => { 
let collectionName = req.query.collection; 
let collectionData = req.query.collectionData;

    console.log(collectionData);//Getting {"product_name":"test","product_weight":"45","product_price":"362"}

    console.log(collectionData.product_name); //Getting undefined
    console.log(collectionData.product_price); //Getting undefined
    console.log(collectionData.product_weight);  //Getting undefined
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.parse().

```js
let collectionDataJSON = JSON.parse(collectionData);

console.log(collectionDataJSON.product_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/) library for your util methods,

```
npm i lodash
```

After installation:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const productName = _.get(collectionData, 'product_name', 'default_name')

console.log(productName);
```